# How to pass input in scala through command line

Tags: scala

```
  import scala.io._    

  object Sum {    
     def main(args :Array[String]):Unit = {    

      println("Enter some numbers and press ctrl-c")

     val input = Source.fromInputStream(System.in)

     val lines = input.getLines.toList

     println("Sum "+sum(lines))

   }

   def toInt(in:String):Option[Int] =

      try{

        Some(Integer.parseInt(in.trim))

      }

      catch    {
       case e: NumberFormatException => None    
   } 

   def sum(in :Seq[String]) = {

     val ints = in.flatMap(s=>toInt(s))

      ints.foldLeft(0) ((a,b) => a +b)

     } }
```

I am trying to run this program  after passing input I have press
   ctrl + c but

It gives this message E:\Scala>scala HelloWord.scala Enter some
   numbers and press ctrl-c 1 2 3 Terminate batch job (Y/N)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional observations, note [trait App](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App) to make an object executable, hence not having to declare a `main(...)` function, for instance like this,

```
object Sum extends App {
  import scala.io._
  import scala.util._

  val nums = Source.stdin.getLines.flatMap(v => Try(v.toInt).toOption)
  println(s"Sum: ${nums.sum}")
}
```

Using `Try`, non successful conversions from `String` to `Int` are turned to `None` and flattened out.

Also note objects and classes are capitalized, hence instead of `object sum` by convention we write `object Sum`.

Comment: @elm- While I am running the code you have sent is not printing anything

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an external API. I really like [scallop API](https://github.com/scallop/scallop)

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code. It should work as intended.

```
object Sum {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val lines = io.Source.stdin.getLines
        val numbers = lines.map(_.toInt)
        println(s"Sum: ${numbers.sum}")
    }
}
```

Plus, the correct shortcut to end the input stream is **Ctrl + D**.

Comment: Thanks its working. I am using in windows 7 So for input stream Ctrl + C is working

Comment: -Accepted your answer. Thanks for your help